# algorithm for perfect substring temporarily replacement

Tags: javascript, strings, hashing

I have an interesting question about string and delimiters.

There is a random string `str`.

There are some symbols (OR SEQUENCES OF SYMBOLS) that are predefined and should be temporarily replaced within that string by `replace` function.

The operation should be like the javascript replace

- Step1:

`var str1 = str.replace(/abc/g, 'newchar1').replace(/,/g, 'newchar2');`  // which replaces `abc`occurencies and commas with `newchar1` and `newchar2` respectively.

- Step2:

After some computations I do the "reverse" replacements by doing

```
str1.replace(/newchar1/g, 'abc').replace(/newchar2/g, ',');
```

and expect to have the same number of abc and commas and in the same places as before any changes.

As you understand there are problems with this method:

newchar1 may exist in the string before. and that's a problem.

1. That way I need to create a random hash for each delimiter (let's say 4-character random string) and check first it is not a part of an original string.
2. Moreover, the hashes for each delimiter should differ from each other.
3. Moreover, the hashes should not be the part of each other. Otherwise see what happens, if ("aa", "ac", "cd') - 3 generated hashes for ("abc", ",", "W") respectively. Good enough? Well.. Let's see... See what bad happens with this `str` string:
   `aabcW,kkk ====step1====>  aaacdackkk ====step2====>  abc,d,kkk.` Oh, unexpected result - different number of commas, lost info.

Do you see the problem?

So, what's the algorithm to properly generate, say, five hashes to replace five substrings within a string and making the reverse operation as described above without losing any info?

Any algorithm in javascript but fast would be fine.
And I will provide my solution in a while. I guess there may be better ideas.

Comment: Why not just persist the original string in order to reverse the operation?

Comment: Some changes, replacements, updates are actually expected in the original string between Step1 and Step2. I decided it's beside the question description. That's why I didn't say about that. That replecement should not / won't touch the hashes (== delimiters == that special substrings).

Comment: How can you be sure that "replacement" won't accidentally create the same sequence like you have generated? And if the replacement code won't touch anything inside `== ==`, then you can just use sequential numbers to denote escaped value, stored like `var map = { "1": ''abc", "2": "," ...}`. Then you can find all placeholders with simple regex `==\d+==` to build the "new original" string using the stored `map`. Obviously, it assumes that "original" string  should have no `==\d+==` sequences of its own - if it has, then you would have to escape them regardless of the chosen approach.

Comment: How can you be sure that "replacement" won't accidentally create the same sequence like you have generated?   - Do you mean why I'm sure I don't get collisions by choosing replacements by the described algorythm? Thr anseer is: if aaa is not met in the string, then aaa1aaa is the replacement for the first symbol to be replaced multiple times. No more than two "a" from any side from "aaa1aaa" won't mess it because we will replace "aaa1aaa" back. It's not met in the string unless it was a replacement.

Comment: @Haradzieniec I mean, what if you have a string `aabb,data1,abc` that is turned according to your algorithm into `aabbaaa1aaadata1aaa1aaaccc1ccc` and your replacement code replaces `bb` with `a1`? You will have `aaa1aaa1aaadata1aaa1aaaccc1ccc ` that will be reversed to `,1aaadata1,abc` - obviously incorrect result. And what about the `==` delimiters you mentioned? Also, what are you trying to accomplish with that "replacement" code? Perhaps there is a much simpler solution to your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @EugenePodskal Per my suggested algorithm "aabb,data1,abc".replace(/,/g,"aaa1aaa").replace(/abc/g,"ccc1ccc");  , correct, I get "aabbaaa1aaadata1aaa1aaaccc1ccc". And then doing "aabbaaa1aaadata1aaa1aaaccc1ccc".replace(/aaa1aaa/g,",").replace(/ccc1ccc/g,"abc")  I get "aabb,data1,abc" which is exactly the original "aabb,data1,abc".

Comment: @Haradzieniec You were talking about `Some changes, replacements, updates are actually expected in the original string between Step1 and Step2` and I meant that those changes (not the "hashing" to escape commas/abc) may produce the "hash" that shouldn't be there, so then it will be impossible to correctly "restore" the string. For example, `var src = "aabb,"; var escaped = escape(src) /*aabbaaa1aaa*/; var replaced = replace(escaped); /*aaa1aaa1aaa*/; var unescaped = unescaped(replaced); /*,1aaa*/`.

Comment: Eugene, thank you, You are right regarding the note _Some changes, replacements, updates are actually expected in the original string between Step1 and Step2 and I meant that those changes may produce the "hash" that shouldn't be there. _   Good point! The changes applied between Step1 and Step2 actually (yes, I had to say about that but even didn't think of that) change NOT the latin letters a_zA_Z within the original string and NOT the existing hashes. Based on that, for latin-number hashes, does the algorithm look resistible on changes in between Step1 and Step2? Will it work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**So, here is my answer for** 
*What's the algorithm to properly generate let's call five hashes to replace five substrings within a string and making the reverse operation as described above without losing any info?*

Let's give a try...

Create the shortest "aaaa...a" string that doesn't occur within an original `str` string. Let it be "aaaaaa" (six "a").

Then add any symbol. Let it be "1". The first "hash" for the string is ready: "aaaaaa1aaaaaa".

The second would be "bb1bb" (or "bb2bb" or whatever in the middle) if no bb mets in the string.

The third would be "ccc1ccc" (or "ccc9ccc" or whatever in the middle) if no ccc mets in the string (otherwise, if ccc mets in the string, then check for occurence of four cccc and use "cccc9cccc").

The fours would be "ddddddddd1ddddddddd"

And the fifth would be "e1e" (if no "e" characters met in the `str` at all).

**Possible questions/comments for my algorithm above:**

1. Why do I need "aaaaaa1aaaaaa" but not "aaaaaa"? that's because "a" may be met right before the first "delimiter". I don't want to grab upon the reverse step the first a but not last from "aaaaaa". That's why I suggest "aaaaaa1aaaaaa".
2. To make these hashes shorter, two letters (not one) may be used to create hashes: let's say any combination of (a, b) letters for the first "hash", (c, d) for the second hash and so on. The hashes expected to take less bytes at average.

Do you like my algorithm or I'm missing something?
And it should be pretty fast in JavaScript to generate.

Any comments are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. There are two Unicode characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), U+FFFE and U+FFFF, which are reserved, do not represent actual characters, and which Unicode says *are intended for process-internal uses*.

Since no valid Unicode string can contain them, you can remove any that are present in your input, use them (or combinations of them) as replacements, and then substitute the original strings for them at the end without concern that there are valid occurrences of them in the string.

There are other Unicode noncharacters that could also be used. See the Unicode [Private-Use Characters, Noncharacters & Sentinels FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) for more information. Note that if you do use noncharacters you must only use them internally; they must be stripped out of the text before you save it, send it on, or otherwise pass it to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

With utf-16 you have 1,112,064 characters. So any string shorter than a million characters will give you over a hundred thousand possible replacement characters.

In general I don't think it is possible to make unique placeholders simply by adding character to them. There is always be a string which when converted gives an ambiguous result.

Comment: Good point. Thank you. However (yes, just the theory), what if the string is even rather longer? Will this algorithm work faster than mine for long strings?

Comment: i dont believe your algorithm works ',1,' -> 'a1a1a1a'

Comment: I understand what you mean but nope, it works:  'a1a1a1a'.replace(/a1a/g,",")  (replace all occurrences of "a1a" with "," in JavaScript). The result will be EXACTLY the original str ",1,".

Comment: Any examples when my algorithm does NOT work are appreciated with no jokes.